# flutter convert 3d points to 2d points

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d, flutter-layout

I have 3d points from an obj,i want to be able to select a point say `v -0.822220 0.216242 -0.025730` and overlay it with a container and save the point.(I have a vehicle 3d obj ,I want to be able to select say the drivers door and save the point selected maybe a door handle).

sample points:

`v 0.822220 0.216242 -0.025730 v -0.822220 0.216242 -0.025730 v 0.811726 0.220845 0.029668 v -0.811726 0.220845 0.029668 v 0.777874 0.214472 0.075458 v -0.777874 0.214472 0.075458 v 0.724172 0.189587 0.073470 v -0.724172 0.189587 0.073470 v 0.704111 0.180226 0.027508`

what i have achieved

```
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
      child: new Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
         Object3D(...),
        new Positioned(
          child: new Container(color:Colors.red),
          left: posx,
          top: posy,
        )
      ]),
    );

void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }
```

.i got a suggestion to convert the points to 2d and use the 2d points to overlay the container.How do i convert the 3d points to 2d points?

Is there a better way of doing this?

i'm using this package [flutter_3d_obj](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_3d_obj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: 3D graphics in Dart/Flutter are extremely experimental. Flutter does not provide any 3D rendering context to draw 3D objects onto, and any 3D rendering packages such as flutter_3d_obj are A) software-based and therefore very slow, and B) extremely limited in feature set [i.e. lacking lighting, shading, normals, texturing, etc.]. As such, it's not recommended to try and draw 3D objects in Flutter directly. The recommendation is to either use something like* [flare](https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter) *to replicate the 3D effect using 2D animations or to use something like the* [Unity3D Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) *package to draw 3D graphics on a non-Flutter canvas.)*

---

The conversion from a point in a 3D space to a 2D plane is called a [Projection Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)). This transformation is the basis of all "cameras" in 3D software from simple games to 3D animated Hollywood films. There are quite a few excellent write-ups on how a projection transformation works (a Google search brings up [this one](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/building-basic-perspective-projection-matrix)), but an overly simplified explanation is as follows.

*(Like any other transformation, this will require linear algebra and matrix multiplication. Fortunately, Dart has a matrix math package in [vector_math](https://pub.dev/packages/vector_math).)*

There are two general types of projection transformations: perspective and orthogonal.

Orthogonal is the easiest to conceptualize and implement, as it's just a flat conversion from a point in 3D space to the place on the plane that is closest to that point. It's literally just stripping the Z coordinate off of the 3D point and using the X and Y coordinates as your new 2D point:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';

Vector2 transformPointOrtho(Vector3 input) {
  final ortho = Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
  );
  return (ortho * input).xy;
}
```

Perspective is more complex, as it also takes perspective (a.k.a field of view angles) into account. As such, there are some parameters that go into creating the transformation matrix:

[image]

- n = Near clipping plane
- f = Far clipping plane
- S = Representation of the vertical viewing angle, derived by the following equation:

[image]

- fov = Field of view (FOV) angle in degrees

  - (To use radians, omit the "* (π/180)" part)

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';

Vector2 transformPointPersp(Vector3 input, double fovDeg, double nearClip, double farClip) {
  final s = 1 / (tan((fovDeg / 2) * (pi / 180)));
  final fdfn = -farClip / (farClip - nearClip);
  final fndfn = -(farClip * nearClip) / (farClip - nearClip);
  final persp = Matrix4(
    s, 0, 0, 0,
    0, s, 0, 0,
    0, 0, fdfn, -1,
    0, 0, fndfn, 0,
  );
  return (input * persp).xy;
}
```

---

Obviously, this is an overly simplistic explanation and doesn't take into account factors such as camera position/rotation. This is also the simplest way to form the transformation matrices, and not necessarily the best. For further reading, I highly suggest you look at various linear algebra and low-level 3D rendering tutorials (such as the one linked above).